# What are best practices for caching and invalidation of db request in doctrine2 with symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I have a strange code from repository inspired by 
"Also Ocramius (a Doctrine2 devel) say it here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/doctrine-user/RIeH8ZkKyEY/HnR7h2p0lCQJ"

```
    public function findAll()
    {
        /* @var $query \Doctrine\ORM\Query */
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery();

        if ($query->getQueryCacheDriver()->contains('cache_key')) {
            return $query->getQueryCacheDriver()->fetch('cache_key');
        }

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT c FROM AppBundle:Culture c'
            );

        try {
            $results = $query->getResult();
            $query->getQueryCacheDriver()->save('cache_key', $results, 300);
            return $results;
        } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I don't want to use $query->useResultCache(true, 60, 'another_cach_key'); because it parses request 'SELECT c FROM AppBundle:Culture c' which reduces performance. So I decided to use QueryCacheDriver.

But to get it I have to create empty Query! 
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery();

And for invalidation in controller

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($culture);
    $em->flush();

    // cache invalidation!
    $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->createQuery()->
    getQueryCacheDriver()->delete('cache_key');
```

I think this code smells. But don't know how to fix it! Can anyone advise best practices?

In common I want store my data and invalidate it on some events.